# SOLR Nested Documents filtered ok, but not sorted by relevance

Tags: solr, lucene, nested-documents

I have this query:

> +parent_field:blabla +*query*:{!parent which=type:parent}+child_field:xxx~1

and in **FL**

> parent_field,[child parentFilter=type:parent childFilter=child_field:xxx~1]

It works fine, meaning that:
It filters the parents that have **parent_field=blabla** and has **at least one child** which has **child_field=xxx**
And it returns from parent: **parent_field** along with a **children list**
the children list is **filtered by: child_field=xxx**, which is **good**
but **the ORDER of relevance**, of children list, is not taken into account, it's always the same order. The order of the Parents indeed is ok.

Example:
This is what it returns

```
{
  parent_field: "blabla",
  children: [
    {
      child_field: "xxxx"
    },{
      child_field: "xxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I want it to return!

```
{
  parent_field: "blabla",
  children: [
    {
      child_field: "xxx"
    },{
      child_field: "xxxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out. I just used sub-queries !

> q=(type_s:parent AND parent_field:blabla)&fl=*,children:[subquery]&children.q=({!terms f=fk_id_parent v=$row.id_parent} AND child_field:xxx~1)